# Enforce element from a map used by a thread should not be used by another thread until first thread completes execution

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a Map say

`HashMap<String, String> init = new Hashmap<String, String>`

and map has 3 elements.
[("one","alpha"),("two","beta"),("three","theta")]

Now I have to run five threads in parallel, using any of pair from above map such that only free pair should be used by new thread.

I mean, no two threads running in parallel should have same pair of values.
Need to enforce whatever thread is running, the pair of values used by that thread should not be used by another thread at same time

Map has pool of values and any pair free in it should be assigned to thread

Comment: Note that calling put from multiple threads not safe with a normal map, even if all threads access distinct elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just removed every element from the Map, when a Thread is choosing to use it.
Therefore you would need to use a Hashtable instead of a Hashmap, so that there will be no problem when multiple threads are modifing it at the same time. (Hash Table is synchronized, HashMap not).

```
Map<String, String> init = new Hashtable<String, String>()
```

PS: always use the according interfaces for variable definitions, so that you can swap out the specific class when needed

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.
The Map should behave like a pool of values in it
Such that new thread should use any pair from it which is free(not being used any current running thread)

Comment: Okay then you could remove an object when its used and when the thread doesnt need it anymore it can put it back into the map. Do alway need all elements in the map, no matter if they are used or not ?

Comment: i dont want to modify any value in the map. just want threads read a pair which ever is free.
Threads need to access map randomly and use free pair which is not being used by any other threads

Comment: You need a way to indicate that a element is _used_ and you need to make that indicator thread safe. An easy way would be two maps: one for used elements and one for free elements. When both maps are thread safe you can let your thread move the elements to the used map when the thread is using it and move it back when it's done

Answer (score 1):

I think a better solution is to replace the `Map` with a `BlockingQueue` and use a custom type to represent the pairs / tuples.

- You instantiate the queue with a concurrent queue type and populate it with all of the pairs / tuples.
- Each thread takes a pair from the front of the queue, blocking if none is available.
- When the thread is finished, it adds the pair to the back of the queue.

The synchronization happens with the `Queue::take` operation.

This design ensures that no pair is used by two threads at the same time.